# Why am I getting a local reference table overflow?

Tags: android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm trying to figure out how to resolve a crash happening on my code when the number of cue points is high. My test reproduce it every time with a number of 530 cue items. Each cue has a `dataSize` of 1.

You can see my code below. Essentially `native_update_cue_points` is called from the java layer. This triggers multiple calls to the java layer from jni layer. Somehow this is causing a table overflow. I'm thinking somehow each call to the static java function is not releasing the allocated string values causing the stack overflow?

**Sample code**

```
static void native_update_cue_points(JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz)
{
    if (smpMediaPlayer)
    {
        std::list<Cue> cuePoints;

        smpMediaPlayer->getCuePoints(&cuePoints);

        for (std::list<Cue>::iterator it = cuePoints.begin(); it != cuePoints.end(); it++)
        {
            Cue cue = *it;

            java_update_cue_point(env, clazz, smFields.global_ref_thiz, 0, &cue);
        }
    }
}

static void java_update_cue_point (JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz, jobject thiz, int reqType, Cue *pCue)
{
    if (!pCue) {
        return;
    }

    jlong id = pCue->id;
    jint type = pCue->type;
    jint extra = pCue->extra;
    jlong pos = pCue->pos;
    jlong duration = pCue->duration;
    jobjectArray jkeys = NULL;
    jobjectArray jvalues = NULL;

    int dataSize = pCue->data.size();

    if (0 < dataSize)
    {
        jkeys = env->NewObjectArray(dataSize, env->FindClass("java/lang/String"), NULL);
        jvalues = env->NewObjectArray(dataSize, env->FindClass("[B"), NULL);

        int position = 0;
        for (std::map<std::string, std::string>::iterator it = pCue->data.begin(); it != pCue->data.end(); it++)
        {
            // set key
            env->SetObjectArrayElement(jkeys, position, env->NewStringUTF(it->first.c_str()));

            // set value
            jbyteArray byteArray = env->NewByteArray(it->second.length());
            env->SetByteArrayRegion(byteArray, 0, it->second.length(), (const signed char *)it->second.c_str());
            env->SetObjectArrayElement(jvalues, position, byteArray);
            env->DeleteLocalRef(byteArray);

            position++;
        }
    }

    // report update
    env->CallStaticVoidMethod(
                clazz,
                smFields.native_callback_add_cue_point,
                thiz,
                (jint)reqType, id, type, extra, pos, duration, jkeys, jvalues);
}
```

**Stacktrace**

```
JNI ERROR (app bug): local reference table overflow (max=512)
 local reference table dump:
   Last 10 entries (of 512):
       511: 0x13054090 java.lang.String[] (1 elements)
       510: 0x70732980 java.lang.Class<java.lang.String>
       509: 0x130517c0 java.lang.String "song_artist"
       508: 0x13054080 byte[][] (1 elements)
       507: 0x7079af18 java.lang.Class<byte[]>
       506: 0x13054070 java.lang.String[] (1 elements)
       505: 0x70732980 java.lang.Class<java.lang.String>
       504: 0x13051700 java.lang.String "song_artist"
       503: 0x12d17ff0 byte[][] (1 elements)
       502: 0x7079af18 java.lang.Class<byte[]>
   Summary:
       205 of java.lang.Class (2 unique instances)
       103 of java.lang.String[] (1 elements) (103 unique instances)
       102 of java.lang.String (102 unique instances)
       102 of byte[][] (1 elements) (102 unique instances)
```

---

**UPDATE 1:**
I did a bit more digging and was able to narrow it down to the call FindClass. This leaves me even more confused! :/ Here is my simplified `native_update_cue_point` method. Do I need to release somehow the FindClass call!?

**Code**

```
static void java_update_cue_point (JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz, jobject thiz, int reqType, Cue *pCue)
{
    jclass jstringClass = env->FindClass("java/lang/String");
}
```

**Stacktrace**

```
JNI ERROR (app bug): local reference table overflow (max=512)
 local reference table dump:
   Last 10 entries (of 512):
       511: 0x70732980 java.lang.Class<java.lang.String>
       510: 0x70732980 java.lang.Class<java.lang.String>
       509: 0x70732980 java.lang.Class<java.lang.String>
       508: 0x70732980 java.lang.Class<java.lang.String>
       507: 0x70732980 java.lang.Class<java.lang.String>
       506: 0x70732980 java.lang.Class<java.lang.String>
       505: 0x70732980 java.lang.Class<java.lang.String>
       504: 0x70732980 java.lang.Class<java.lang.String>
       503: 0x70732980 java.lang.Class<java.lang.String>
       502: 0x70732980 java.lang.Class<java.lang.String>
   Summary:
       512 of java.lang.Class (1 unique instances)
```

---

**UPDATE 2:**
I was able to fix the table overflow by doing a `DeleteLocalRef` on every local object regardless if the java VM would take care of it. My thoughts are that the VM is accumulating items on the stack which will release after executing. I need to remove each item explicitly from the stack to avoid unwanted accumulations for later removal while on a large loop.

Still I'm left feeling like I haven't understood completely why this is happening and why my solution solves it.

**Fixed code**

```
static void java_update_cue_point (JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz, jobject thiz, int reqType, Cue *pCue)
{
    if (!pCue) {
        return;
    }

    jclass jstringClass = env->FindClass("java/lang/String");
    jclass jbyteArrayClass = env->FindClass("[B");
    jlong id = pCue->id;
    jint type = pCue->type;
    jint extra = pCue->extra;
    jlong pos = pCue->pos;
    jlong duration = pCue->duration;
    jobjectArray jkeys = NULL;
    jobjectArray jvalues = NULL;

    int dataSize = pCue->data.size();

    if (0 < dataSize)
    {
        jkeys = env->NewObjectArray(dataSize, jstringClass, NULL);
        jvalues = env->NewObjectArray(dataSize, jbyteArrayClass, NULL);

        int position = 0;
        for (std::map<std::string, std::string>::iterator it = pCue->data.begin(); it != pCue->data.end(); it++)
        {
            // set key
            jstring jkey = env->NewStringUTF(it->first.c_str());
            env->SetObjectArrayElement(jkeys, position, jkey);
            env->DeleteLocalRef(jkey); // FIX

            // set value
            jbyteArray byteArray = env->NewByteArray(it->second.length());
            env->SetByteArrayRegion(byteArray, 0, it->second.length(), (const signed char *)it->second.c_str());
            env->SetObjectArrayElement(jvalues, position, byteArray);
            env->DeleteLocalRef(byteArray);

            position++;
        }
    }

    // report update
    env->CallStaticVoidMethod(
                clazz,
                smFields.native_callback_add_cue_point,
                thiz,
                (jint)reqType, id, type, extra, pos, duration, jkeys, jvalues);

    if (jkeys) {
        env->DeleteLocalRef(jkeys); // FIX
    }

    if (jvalues) {
        env->DeleteLocalRef(jvalues); // FIX
    }

    if (jstringClass) {
        env->DeleteLocalRef(jstringClass); // FIX
    }

    if (jbyteArrayClass) {
        env->DeleteLocalRef(jbyteArrayClass); // FIX
    }
}
```

Comment: [`FindClass`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#FindClass) returns an object. You only don't need to call [`DeleteLocalRef`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#DeleteLocalRef) if you won't [run out](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/design.html#global_and_local_references).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're creating too many local references (two for classes, two for object arrays and some more for strings and byte arrays *per run* of `java_update_cue_point`). The VM can only handle a limited amount of local references. See "[Referencing Java Objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/design.html#referencing_java_objects)" for some documentation. The "[Global and Local References](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#global_and_local_references)" section in the JNI function documentation also has some details. The VM will free local references automatically when a native method returns, but in a loop like yours you will have to delete references you don't need anymore with `DeleteLocalRef`.

To optimize a little, my recommendation would be to do the two `FindClass` calls outside of the loop in `native_update_cue_points` and pass them as parameters to `java_update_cue_point`. This way you'll only have two references for the class objects that the VM will free for you when `native_update_cue_points` returns, and you save processing time by not finding the same classes over and over again.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you need to call `DeleteLocalRef()` on the Java `String` object created in this line of code:

```
        env->SetObjectArrayElement(jkeys, position, env->NewStringUTF(it->first.c_str()));
```

Your call to `NewStringUTF()` creates a Java object with a local reference, which you do not delete.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So I shouldn't have to delete the local reference from what I been reading. However, I did try that and also on jkeys and jvalues but the issue was still there. :(

Comment: Post the code you tried.  According to the local reference table dump you posted, you have a lot of `String` references in your local reference table, and from the code you posted those can only be coming from `NewStringUTF()`.  It shouldn't be hard to save the return value from `NewStringUTF()` into a local variable, use the local variable as a parameter to your first `SetObjectArrayElement()` call, then delete the local reference.

Comment: Hey @Andrew please see my update on the question. Things got weird... :/

Comment: @Jona Well, something's holding on to those references to `java.lang.String`.  What's the entire `java_update_cue_point()` look like? It's probably easiest to just delete the local reference to the String class after you're done using it in `java_update_cue_point()` and see what happens.

Comment: Mmm, so calling `DeleteLocalRef` on the `jclass jstringClass` resolves the crash. To me this is odd since no where does it say you must delete the local ref returned by `FindClass`.

Comment: @Jona - Oh, it probably does explain the behavior somewhere in the Java documentation, buried deep in the specifics of some obscure call that has little to do with the subject.  Java did originate with Sun Microsystems, and that was Sun's documentation style that applied to Java and Solaris - everything was documented, you just couldn't find it unless you already knew where to look.  And Oracle has continued the tradition with Java and Solaris.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew, for your input. I have updated my question with the fix. However, I'm not happy with the fix cause it is weird and I don't completely understand why it solves it.

Comment: The VM can only handle so much local references. It will free them automatically when the native method returns but not earlier. If you are accumulating local references in one call, you have to free some of them yourself because space runs out otherwise. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/design.html#referencing_java_objects

Comment: To add to this: my recommendation would be to do the `FindClass` calls outside of your loop in `native_update_cue_points`and pass them as parameters to `java_update_cue_point`. This way you'll only have two references for the class objects that the VM will free for you when `native_update_cue_points` returns, and you save processing time by not finding the same classes over and over again.

Comment: @user2543253 please post your comments as an answer. I believe your input counts to me as a valid answer to my question. Thanks!